# Advantage of Django ORM V/S Performing raw SQL queries

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have been working with django for the past two years but I still can't see the advantage of using `django ORM` rather than writing raw SQL queries.

Is there any memory efficiency advantage? Is there any configuration advantage? Is there any data migrations advantage? What are the situations I should use Django orm?

Why should anyone use Django orm over raw SQL queries?

Comment: Another good [link](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.in/2012/06/when-should-i-use-orm.html) if you want to read.

Comment: + Django ORM properly escaping input parameters and protects from sql injection.
- Some complex queries created by ORM are not perfect. Then you can use   Raw sql..